# cross-domain AJAX post call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, http-post

I've to make a POST call(with parameter) to an asp form which is located on another server.

For development, I did this on the same server, and it works perfectly, but now I'm testing it on another server, and instead of receiving a 200 status, I receive a 0 status.

I think it's because it's a cross-domain AJAX call, it's the only thing which changed. So how can I make this call? Is there any file I can put on the server/client to allow this call(like flash, ...)?

Thank you!

Comment: for futher help we might need to know the natre of the ajax call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assuming you can change the server you connect to

You can implement [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

You need the server to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if you want to allow all domains to access, otherwise return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com`

If you cannot change the server you are accessing, you need to use a proxy on the server your script comes from - alternatively investigate if they have published an API to return for example [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

More details here

- [MDN HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) (how)
- [W3Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (Implemation details)
- [MSDN XDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and several links to the right of this questions

Comment: the support seems quite limited at the moment.

Comment: I took a look at your link, but I can't found where I should declare all these "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ...

Comment: @dvhh - it is supported by most modern browsers i.e. FF3.5+, Safari5, IE8+ (using XDR)

Comment: Okay, so it's seems that what I want isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a proxy script, or use jsonp.
The easier course would be to use a proxy script on your server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to modify anything on the server

Comment: another solution would be to rewrite your ajax call to use an iframe instead (unfortunately this is a little bit doggy)

Comment: @dvhh but he would only be able to send data, not receive any reply

Comment: You cannot do JSONP with a POST request.