# How To post Form data to Cross Domain Without Page Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have tried lot regarding Post form data to Cross domain using Ajax post method. but i received success response. but the Form data is not posted to the requested cross domain instead of shows 404 network error in browser.

can anyone suggest How to Post the Form Data to Cross domain in ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Well I think its better if you share some of your code that is involved in this operation. Seems that the form submit event is not handled correctly as it form is being submitted and the page gets refreshed.

Comment: @KentPawar, his code was hidden, just editted it, though he's only showing part of the code and not the part that he's working with

Comment: this should be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812331/cross-domain-ajax-post-call

Comment: @x4rf41 yup it looked like a cross-domain AJAX post call issue, but I think Anandhsync hasn't implemented the AJAX part as yet.. Otherwise he would have reported a HTTP status error and null responses from the AJAX request..